# Sorting a list of dictionaries based on the order of values of another list

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7.3, and I'm trying to sort a list of dictionaries based on the order of values of another list.

IE:

```
listOne = ['hazel', 'blue', 'green', 'brown']
listTwo = [{'name': 'Steve', 'eyecolor': 'hazel', 'height': '5 ft. 11 inches'},
           {'name': 'Mark', 'eyecolor': 'brown', 'height': '6 ft. 2 inches'},
           {'name': 'Mike', 'eyecolor': 'blue', 'height': '6 ft. 0 inches'},
           {'name': 'Ryan', 'eyecolor': 'brown', 'height': '6 ft, 0 inches'},
           {'name': 'Amy', 'eyecolor': 'green', 'height': '5 ft, 6 inches'}]
```

Sorting listTwo based off of the order of values in listOne, we would end up with the following:

```
print listTwo
[{'name': 'Steve', 'eyecolor': 'hazel', 'height': '5 ft. 11 inches'},
{'name': 'Mike', 'eyecolor': 'blue', 'height': '6 ft. 0 inches'},
{'name': 'Amy', 'eyecolor': 'green', 'height': '5 ft, 6 inches'},
{'name': 'Mark', 'eyecolor': 'brown', 'height': '6 ft. 2 inches'},
{'name': 'Ryan', 'eyecolor': 'brown', 'height': '6 ft, 0 inches'}]
```

I eventually need to output this text, so what I've done to display it correctly (in the correct order) is the following:

```
for x in xrange(len(listOne)):
    for y in xrange(len(listTwo)):
        if listOne[x] == listTwo[y]["eyecolor"]:
            print "Name: " + str(listTwo[y]["name"]),
            print "Eye Color: " + str(listTwo[y]["eyecolor"]),
            print "Height: " + str(listTwo[y]["height"])
```

Is there some sort of lambda expression that can be used to make this happen? There has to be a more compact, less complex way of getting it in the order I want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `list.index` to generate a sort value for your list of dictionaries:

```
listTwo.sort(key=lambda x: listOne.index(x["eyecolor"]))
```

This is a little bit inefficient though, since `list.index` does a linear search through the eye-color list. If you had many eye colors to check against, it would be slow. A somewhat better approach would build an index dictionary instead:

```
order_dict = {color: index for index, color in enumerate(listOne)}
listTwo.sort(key=lambda x: order_dict[x["eyecolor"]])
```

If you don't want to modify `listTwo`, you can use the built-in `sorted` function instead of the `list.sort` method. It returns a sorted copy of the list, rather than sorting in-place.

Comment: That index dictionary was just what I was looking for. I actually do want to sort the list in place, rather than returning a new sorted list, so I'll use list.sort. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have all the items from listTwo in listOne. So I get an error saying `ValueError: 4L is not in list`. How do I resolve by ignoring those items? Or maybe the order should be applied in a default way for those

Comment: A default value would be pretty easy. Just use `order_dict.get(x["eyecolor"], default)` in the second version. The most reasonable defaults are probably `-1` (to sort unknown values at the start) and `float('inf')` (to sort them at the end). Removing the values would be only a bit more complicated. You'd need to use `filter` (or an equivalent list comprehension) before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
listOne = ['hazel', 'blue', 'green', 'brown', 'brown1']
listTwo = [
    {'name': 'Steve', 'eyecolor': 'hazel', 'height': '5 ft. 11 inches'
     },
    {'name': 'Mark', 'eyecolor': 'brown', 'height': '6 ft. 2 inches'},
    {'name': 'Mike', 'eyecolor': 'blue', 'height': '6 ft. 0 inches'},
    {'name': 'Ryan', 'eyecolor': 'brown', 'height': '6 ft, 0 inches'},
    {'name': 'Amy', 'eyecolor': 'green', 'height': '5 ft, 6 inches'},
    {'name': 'Amy', 'eyecolor': 'green2', 'height': '5 ft, 6 inches'},
    ]

print sorted(listTwo, key=lambda i: listOne.index(i['eyecolor']))
```

**Working**

1. First we will iterate through the listTwo and fetch the eyecolor value.
2. Using that eyecolor value, we need to check the index of that value on listOne.
3. Based on that index, we will sort values.

But their is a chance of ValueError for this code while fetching the index. So we need to handle it.

```
print sorted(listTwo, key=lambda i: (listOne.index(i['eyecolor'
             ]) if i['eyecolor'] in listOne else len(listOne) + 1))
```

Comment: why transform the list after creation. You can create it as a dict.

`sequrence_dict = {'hazel': 0, 'blue': 1, 'green': 2, 'brown': 3}`